# Regex match content of specific html tags without specific attribute

Tags: html, regex

I already have a regex for matching the content of specific html tags:

```
/<tag[^>]+>(.+?)<\/tag>/ims
```

but I need to exclude tags that are containing src attribute in any order in their starter tag.

Comment: `<tag(?![^>]*\bsrc\s*=)[^>]*>(.+?)<\/tag>`

Comment: @CrayonViolent That's it. Thanks!